# Swift XCTest fails because plist file can not be found

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

I am currently building a iOS framework project in Swift. I have also a own build target for tests. I also added a new TestSettings.plist file to the test build target. There I store the username / password for the api calls.
But the XCTest now always fails, because it can not load the plist file.

I have already checked that the plist file is in the .xctest folder/bundle

I try to load the plist file with the following code:

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("TestSettings", ofType: "plist") {
            settingsDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
} else {
            XCTFail("API: getAuthToken no TestSettings.plist file found")
}
```

Any ideas what I do wrong, or is there a other way to not put the username/password into the test cases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out the problem, it is not possible to access the mainBundle in XCTest. I had to use the following code to fix it:

```
let path = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType).pathForResource("TestSettings", ofType: "plist")
```

Answer (score 2):

When designing Unit Tests the most basic thing you have to ask yourself is: **what do you want to test** ?

You want to test functionality of your logic and you want it to be fast. 
You don't want to test the *.plist file and you don't want to test if the file is in it's right location.

Do not use files unless you really need to (complex input data for algorithm for example).

You should use **mocks** instead for any database/internet/file communication.

Here's a quick overview if you don't know what mocks are:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/686935/Unit-testing-with-Mock-objects-Rhino-Mocks